# Jquery GET request not being recieved by controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, model-view-controller, thymeleaf

I am trying to get a part of a web page to refresh at an interval.
I am using spring boot in conjunction with thymeleaf for my web application.
I decided to use a jquery get request to contact my mvc controller, however this get request doesn't seem to get processed by the controller.

I have already tried calling the function on load, and this provides no results.

Here is the Ajax function:

```
    function setupRefresh() {
        setInterval(refreshFrame(), 1000);
    }
    function refreshFrame() {
        $.ajax({type: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost:8080/refresh"
    }).done(function (fragment) {
        $("#navbar").replaceWith(fragment);
    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("AJAX call failed: " + textStatus + ", " + errorThrown);
    });
    }
```

This is the div I am trying to refresh:

```html
<nav id="navbar" class="navbar" th:fragment="navbar">
    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search..">
    <div class="mx-auto order-0">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/index">Boxed</a>
    </div>
    <div>Generate Days:</div>
    <a th:text="${currentDay}" th:href="@{/toggleGeneration}" onclick="setupRefresh()"></a>
</nav>
```

Here is my controller

```java
@Controller
public class DataController {

    @Autowired
    private DayService dayService;

    @GetMapping(value = "/refresh")
    public String refreshNumber(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("currentDay", dayService.findHighest().getDayNr());
        return "index.html :: #navbar";
    }
}
```

It seems the get request is not even being performed, as I don't even get an error alert on the page. Everything written outside the get request is performed, however the request itself is giving me nothing.

Comment: change url to `/refresh` and remove `http://localhost:8080` part.

Comment: I just tried this, however the get is still not being performed. The strange thing is that it seems not to get performed at all, and doesn't even give a failure message.

Comment: try debugging and see if it is hitting your controller or not. also remove `#` from  `"index.html :: #navbar"`

Answer (score 0):

This might be a problem with your `$.ajax` function.

Take a look on how it should be (**GET**):

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

And **POST**:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

And what is GET and POST?

**GET** pass data as URL parameters, so you can see and modify it. GET is faster than POST.

**POST** is a most secure way, as it pass data through HTTP request.

Hope this helps!

Brhaka

Answer (score 0):

You probably already found the answer by yourself, but you need to add function call, for example, add it to onload (as you tried to do). Then delete "http://localhost:8080/" from ajax url parameter, at least for me it always works without leading slash. I'm not sure about the way you returning data from controller because I do it in another way.

```
function myFunction() {
  setInterval(ajaxFunc, 1000);
}

function ajaxFunc() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "refresh"
    }).done(function (fragment) {
        $("#navbar").replaceWith(fragment);
    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("AJAX call failed");
    });
}

window.onload = function() {
    myFunction();
};
```